# PHP extensions - call your own PHP function from another PHP function

Tags: php, c, php-extension

Let's say we have a custom PHP extension like:

```
PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(myextension)
{
   // How do I call myfunction() from here?
   return SUCCESS;
}
PHP_FUNCTION(myfunction)
{
   // Do something here
   ...
   RETURN_NULL;
}
```

How can I call myfunction() from the RSHUTDOWN handler?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I was trying to think of a way to call json_encode from inside a custom ext. function and couldn't figure out how to pull it off.

Comment: call_user_func('json_encode', $param);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the provided macros the call will be:

```
PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(myextension)
{
   ZEND_FN(myFunction)(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0 TSRMLS_CC);
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

When you're defining you function as `PHP_FUNCTION(myFunction)` the preprocessor will expand you're definition to:

```
ZEND_FN(myFunction)(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS)
```

which in turn is:

```
zif_myFunction(int ht, zval *return_value, zval **return_value_ptr, zval *this_ptr, int return_value_used TSRMLS_DC)
```

The macros from zend.h and php.h:

```
#define PHP_FUNCTION            ZEND_FUNCTION
#define ZEND_FUNCTION(name)         ZEND_NAMED_FUNCTION(ZEND_FN(name))
#define ZEND_FN(name)                       zif_##name
#define ZEND_NAMED_FUNCTION(name)       void name(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS)
#define INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS int ht, zval *return_value, zval **return_value_ptr, zval *this_ptr, int return_value_used TSRMLS_DC
#define INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAM_PASSTHRU ht, return_value, return_value_ptr, this_ptr, return_value_used TSRMLS_CC
```

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you make the PHP_FUNCTION a stub like so:

```
void doStuff()
{
  // Do something here
  ...
}

PHP_RSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(myextension)
{
   doStuff();
   return SUCCESS;
}
PHP_FUNCTION(myfunction)
{
   doStuff();
   RETURN_NULL;
}
```